# Unity launcher stays behind windows

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher

I have been having a problem with Unity launcher recently. Launcher stay behind my windows and I can't bring it to the front of my windows! [image: Hud open behind of windows]

[image: Nautilus is over and front of menus]

As you can see, the Nautilus window is in front of the launcher menu and the menus are totally inaccessible when the window is maximized.

Comment: The HUD will remain in front of the launcher. This is a feature. Other than that, what window are you talking about?

Comment: Hud, launcher, menus and everthing that belong to it stay behind of windows.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot explaining that, other than one you have posted above?

Comment: I added another screenshot. As you can see menus are behind windows and when windows are maximized they are totaly inaccessible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type this following to solve this problem:

```
unity&disown
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to generating this commands, you'll see screen will flick a few times, just don't panic ! Wait for a few second and everything will back to normal again

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem but is there any way to prevent this problem?

Comment: I will also be intrested in a permanent solution, as the `unity&disown` command will mess up all my windows desktop positions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea on what might be causing it to look deeper in to the matter?

Comment: Just a word of caution: save all your documents before doing so! it fixed the problem, but also killed all my running applications. (UBUNTU 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved for me after shutting down and restarting. The Unity application launcher now correctly appears in front of any other window.

For me the `unity&disown` solution didn't work - it actually made the entire unity UI permanently disappear until restarted, including the top part of every window with the close, minimize and maximize buttons. Even after waiting ~20 minutes the UI didn't reappear and I couldn't close any windows to see if there was possibly a dialog box waiting for my response hidden somewhere, so I had to force a shutdown by holding the power button for 4+ seconds.

The issue occurred after suspending and waking up my machine several times, although I'm not positive the two events are correlated.

Hope this helps anyone else having trouble with the `unity&disown` solution.